# Baroque composing

Tags: composition, baroque-period

What defines a "trio" style. As in, if I were composing a piece on the piano how do I compose it in a "trio" style

Comment: Welcome to Music.SE! I assume you mean "trio" as in a "trio sonata"?

Comment: @Richard another possibility would be a contrasting, more lightly orchestrated middle section of a larger movement.

Comment: @phoog Very true! I was debating with myself if that was more Classical than Baroque.

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid you'll need to explain a little more. "Trio" can have a few meanings, and they don't directly define styles: 1) a piece for three players; 2) a baroque "trio sonata," which says more about how the parts are put together, in a "melody/bass/chords" texture; or 3) a "trio" section of a "[minuet-and-trio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuet#Minuet_and_trio)," which at first used fewer players but eventually applied the word to a formal section regardless of how many people play.

Comment: @AndyBonner what does "trio sonata" say about a baroque piece beyond that it is for two solo instruments plus b.c.?

Comment: And as the title is "Baroque composing", why do you want to write for piano and not for harpsichord?

Comment: @phoog Is the usage of the "trio" section baroque? I associate it with Haydn and later.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I think the practice has its roots in the baroque (e.g. Handel's Water Music has some _da capo_ forms with reduced textures in the middle section, but perhaps not strictly trios).  I don't suppose, however, that the practice of labeling it "trio" was universally established before the later 18th or even 19th century.  This is my very unscientific impression, though, unsupported by any survey or other study.

Comment: @cdalitz the piano's inventor was born in 1655, 30 years before Bach and Handel, and the piano was invented around 1700, 50 years before the baroque period is commonly said to have ended.  Of course, those pianos were not much like a modern piano.

Comment: @phoog I thought that "baroque composing" meant mainstream baroque and mainstream baroque instruments. But maybe this was an overinterpretation, as the question lacks essential information about the intended aims. It was thus just a suggestion to think about the nexus between period style and period instruments.

Comment: @cdalitz it seems that keyboard composition in the baroque was not as specific as we typically think of it today.  It would have been fairly unremarkable for most pieces to be played on the harpsichord, clavichord, piano or organ.  The question certainly would benefit from more specifics about the asker's goals -- I could even imagine that Mr. Liszt wants to know about composing "baroque style" music as it was done in the 19th century, in which case a modern piano would be the more appropriate instrument (I'm thinking for example of Brahms, not sure whether the original Franz Liszt did this.)

Comment: @phoog I am not aware of an example by "The Real Franz Liszt", but Schumann wrote 1854 four fuges for piano. De la Motte remarked in his counter point text book that these fugues sound more like Bach than Bach himself. Because of this caveat, I try to introduce whimsical "non-strict" moments in my own fugues, like the solo general pause or the bass cadenca in this fugue (the actual fuge starts at 49s): https://youtu.be/XD0tpRBcwMY Incidentally it is a trio, so maybe exactly what the "Non-Real Franz Liszt" was asking for.